# c socket programming, Error in receiving a line

Tags: c, sockets

I have modified a code of simple chat program using Socket programming in C.My problem is that i have to enter two lines at either server or client to receive only one line by the other.I have uploaded an image to explain more. Any help is appreciated

```
SERVER
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define SERVER_TCP_PORT 3000
#define BUFLEN 256

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    int n,bytes_to_read;
    int sd,new_sd,client_len,port;
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    char *bp,buf[BUFLEN];

    switch (argc) {
        case 1:
            port = SERVER_TCP_PORT;
            break;
        case 2:
            port = atoi (argv[1]);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf (stderr,"Usage: %s[port]\n",argv[0]);
            exit(1);
            }
    /*Create a system socket */

        if ((sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1){
            fprintf(stderr,"Can't create a socket\n");
            exit(1);
            }

    /*Bind an address to the socket*/

    bzero ((char*)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server))==-1){
        fprintf(stderr,"can't bind name to socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /*queue up to 5 connect requests*/

    listen(sd,5);
    while(1){
        client_len = sizeof(client);
    if((new_sd = accept(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&client_len))==-1){
        fprintf(stderr,"can't accept client \n");
        exit(1);
        }

if(fork())
{
printf("\n Server listening to clients on port 2000");
printf("\n Server got request from%s",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
printf("\n SEND DATA<q or Q to quit> :%s",buf);
scanf("%s",buf);
while((strcmp(buf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(buf,"Q")!=0))
{
send(new_sd,buf,30,0);
scanf("%s",buf);

}
send(new_sd,"q",5,0);
}
else{
n = recv(new_sd,buf,30,0);
while((strcmp(buf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(buf,"Q")!=0))
{
printf("\nRECEIVED DATA =%s",buf);
n = recv(new_sd,buf,30,0);

}
printf("\n Bye");
send(new_sd,"EOF",4,0);
close(sd);
close(new_sd);
}
}
return 0;
} 



Client
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define SERVER_TCP_PORT 3000
#define BUFLEN 256
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

int n,bytes_to_read;
int sd,port;
struct hostent *hp;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char *host,*bp,rbuf[BUFLEN],sbuf[BUFLEN];
switch(argc) {
    case 2:
        host = argv[1];
        port = SERVER_TCP_PORT;
        break;
    case 3:
        host = argv[1];
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s host[port] \n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
        }

/*Create a stream socket*/

if ((sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Can't create a socket\n");
    exit(1);
    }
bzero ((char *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(port);
if((hp = gethostbyname(host))==NULL){
    fprintf (stderr,"Can't get server's address\n");
    exit(1);
    }
bcopy(hp->h_addr,(char *)&server.sin_addr,hp->h_length);
/*connecting to the server*/

if (connect (sd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server))==-1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Can't connect \n");
    exit(1);
    }
printf("Connected:server's address is %s\n",hp->h_name);

if(fork())
{
bzero(rbuf,30);
printf("\n SEND DATA<q or Q to quit> :%s",rbuf);
scanf("%s",rbuf);
while((strcmp(rbuf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(rbuf,"Q")!=0))
{
send(sd,rbuf,30,0);
scanf("%s",rbuf);

} 
send(sd,"q",5,0);
}

else{
n = recv(sd,rbuf,30,0);
while((strcmp(rbuf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(rbuf,"Q")!=0))
{
printf("\nRECEIVED DATA =%s",rbuf);
n = recv(sd,rbuf,30,0);

}
printf("\n Bye");
send(sd,"EOF",4,0);
close(sd);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: recv() function reads "some" data from the network stream. you need size of the strings in order to get them one by one. Therefore, you should encapsulate the lines (strings) with a header that contains the character count.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but i didn't quit follow you, would you explain a little bit more

Comment: Please format your code properly, this is merely readable.

Comment: @PrototypeStark: I wouldn't recommend it. it would be better to loop until a complete buffer is received or sent (as neither `send` or `recv` guarantee a complete read/write for stream sockets). (also, it's called [Nagle's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm))

Answer (score 1):

You are only sending/recieving 30 bytes each time.  Maybe that should be BUFLEN?  better yet, have a fixed size block at the front of the message which includes the `strlen` of the message.

For example:

```
int size = htonl(strlen(buf)+1);
send(new_sd, size, sizeof(size), 0);
send(new_sd, buf, size, 0);
```

Client:

```
int size;
recv(sd, size, sizeof(size),0);
size = ntohl(size);
recv(sd, buf, size, 0);
```

Error checking has been omitted for clarity.

Comment: I changed the BUFLEN to 30,Unfortunately i still have the same problem

Comment: No, change the 30, not BUFLEN!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to read lines one by one. however, recv() function does not deliver the messages to you one by one since it only reads certain amount of data from the message stream. In order to differentiate between messages, there are two ways.

First, you send a fixed-size message -in this case 30 bytes- and always read 30 bytes from the otherside of the network.

Second, you encapsulate your data with a structure that contains the data length so as to provide various-sized messages. This method is better, because if you want to send -let's say- 1024-byte long string, otherside will know it and read 1024 bytes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I must of have done something wrong, I have added the size to the header message and now am not receiving any data fro both client and server. Am using it correctly.
Here is part of the code where i inserted size.

SERVER

```
if(fork())
{
printf("\n Server listening to clients on port 2000");
printf("\n Server got request from%s",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
bzero(buf,256);
printf("\n SEND DATA<q or Q to quit> :%s",buf);
scanf("%s",buf);
while((strcmp(buf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(buf,"Q")!=0))
{
int size = htonl(strlen(buf)+1);
send(new_sd,size,sizeof(size),0);
send(new_sd,buf,size,0);
scanf("%s",buf);

}
send(new_sd,"q",5,0);
}
else{

int size;
recv(new_sd,size,sizeof(size),0);
size=ntohl(size);
n=recv(new_sd,buf,size,0);
while((strcmp(buf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(buf,"Q")!=0))
{
printf("\nRECEIVED DATA =%s",buf);
n = recv(new_sd,buf,size,0);
}
printf("\n Bye");
send(new_sd,"EOF",BUFLEN,0);
close(sd);
close(new_sd);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

CLIENT

```
if(fork())
{
printf("\n SEND DATA<q or Q to quit> :%s",rbuf);
scanf("%s",rbuf);
while((strcmp(rbuf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(rbuf,"Q")!=0))
{
int size = htonl(strlen(sbuf)+1);
send(sd,size,sizeof(size),0);
send(sd,sbuf,size,0);
scanf("%s",sbuf);

} 
send(sd,"q",5,0);
}

else{
int size;
recv(sd,size,sizeof(size),0);
size = ntohl(size);
recv(sd,rbuf,size,0);
while((strcmp(rbuf,"q")!=0)&&(strcmp(rbuf,"Q")!=0))
{
printf("\nRECEIVED DATA =%s",rbuf);
//n = recv(sd,rbuf,bytes_to_read,0);

}
printf("\n Bye");
send(sd,"EOF",4,0);
close(sd);
}

return 0;
}
```